# How to include dynamic content in URL parameters vue js

Tags: vue.js, url, parameters, parameter-passing, href

I want to add a parameter to a URL inside a href attribute. I'm using Vue js and those parameters should be dynamic. How can I do this?

```
<a href="localhost/doctors?{{ dynamic content }}">
```

or

```
<a href="localhost/doctors?${"dynamic content"}>
```

not working. Vue gives me an error that I should bind it. but I tried it too. Couldn't make it work. what is the correct way? I'm a newbie to Vue js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use backticks inside the quotes and add data binding on href.

```html
<a :href="`localhost/doctors/${dynamic_content}`">
```

In the above, the `dynamic_content` can be a computed, data, props or any other reactive property.